# HTML formatting only being partially applied using FOR XML PATH and sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-send-dbmail, for-xml-path

I have a SP that identifies and removes old db information that is no longer needed, compiling a list of the accounts that were removed.

I'm sending out an email with the list of these accounts, but for some reason the HTML formatting is only being applied to a part of the message body, can anyone offer a reason/solution to this issue?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (acct varchar(4))
INSERT INTO @table (acct)
SELECT 1234
UNION ALL SELECT 2345
UNION ALL SELECT 3456
UNION ALL SELECT 4567

DECLARE @accountList VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @accountList = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' <br /> ' + acct FROM @table FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

DECLARE @mailBody VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @mailBody = 'The job ran successfully.' +
    '<br /><br />Account List Purged: <br />' + @accountList

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Default',
    @recipients = 'email@email.email',
    @subject = 'Data Purge [Accounts Purged]',
    @body_format = 'html',
    @body = @mailBody
```

Here's what gets sent from the `exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`

[image]

Notice how the `<br />` successfully "applied" for areas outside of the `FOR XML PATH...`, but within it, are written as literals.

Anyone have any experience with this and/or know what i need to do to remediate?

Comment: Try this: `SET @accountList = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' <br /> ' + acct FROM @table FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)'),1,1,'')`

Comment: @wewesthemenace that works!  If you make it an answer Ill mark it as such, but could you also give some information why one works over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)')`.

```
SET @accountList = 
    STUFF((
        SELECT ' <br /> ' + acct 
        FROM @table FOR XML PATH(''), type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    1, 1, '')
```

This prints:

```
<br /> 1234 <br /> 2345 <br /> 3456 <br /> 4567
```

While your query prints:

```
&lt;br /&gt; 1234 &lt;br /&gt; 2345 &lt;br /&gt; 3456 &lt;br /&gt; 4567
```

`FOR XML PATH('')` has problems with XML entitization as it converts `<`, `>` and some other special characters to XML-safe entities. Using `PATH, TYPE).value()` prevents this from happening.

Comment: ah interesting - i didn't think to print `@accountList` to see what the literal value was, thanks for the explanation :)